# Closing log4j Logger to release File Descriptor

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have written a Server that receives RMI requests and performs some operations.

For each request a Log4J Logger instance is created. Following is the code snippet which is used for creating Logger instance.

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("log_" + requestID);
log.setAdditivity(false);
FileAppender appender = null;
try {
    PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%-5p %C{1} %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} : %m%n");
    appender = new FileAppender(layout, logFileName, false);
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error initializing logger", e);
}

log.addAppender(appender);
log.setLevel(level);
```

Things work fine here. The problem is overtime after receiving a lot of requests, the numbe of Open Files for this server process increases and does not come down thus crashing the process with an Exception saying **Too Many Open Files**.

Upon further inspection it was identified that the problem is because of the File Descriptors are not released after the the request is complete. I have tried looking through the Log4J documentation but could not find anything on how can I close just one logger without affecting the others that might be running in different threads.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [FileAppender.close() documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/WriterAppender.html#close%28%29), maybe it will solve your issue.

But I think that you should reconsider your design, and only have one Logger instance, no ?

Comment: Thanks. Looking at that now. It feels silly to have miss something so obvious. Reason I am creating different logger instances for each request is to have a different Log files for separate requests. This makes things easier when I want to debug a Specific request that has failed.

Answer (score 1):

Make your logger final static should fix the problem:

```
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(YOURCLASS.class);
```