# log4j2's idlePurgePolicy doesnt work within a container

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j2

Previously I found that idlePurgePolicy will close open log files after an idle period ([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165886/too-many-open-files-due-to-log4j-config)).

However now it would seem that log4j2's idlePurgePolicy doesnt work within a container.  I have tested the below in a single java app and it works as expected (closing idle log files) but in a container (in the example below) the log files are left open.

I have an example project that is a Spring Web Service running on Tomcat.  There is a rest api that when called logs a single statement; since this is backed by a file appender log4j also creates/opens a log file.

**Strangely enough (and slightly contradictory here) the idlePurgePolicy does seem to work the first time the rest api is called.  but after that no log files are ever closed**.  This kinda suggest that it could be a threading issue however I did create threads and thread pools in my simple java app and could not replicate the issue.  I also logged thread name and id which revealed that all the threads spring is spawning for the logging are new (so the pool aspect or re-using threads isn't really coming into play, the first one that works is the same as all subsequent threads).

Side Note:  I am testing on windows and use [OpenedFilesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html) to view open files (necessary if testing/reproducing this)

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration monitorInterval="180">
    <Properties>
        <!-- change the path to conference logs below to fit your system -->
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">C:\CodeRepos\logs</Property>
        <Property name="PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level
            %logger{36} - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
    <Routing name="ConferenceLog">
        <Routes pattern="${ctx:logFileName}">
            <Route>
                <File name="ConferenceLog"
                    fileName="${LOG_DIR}/conferences/ConferenceLog.log">
                    <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}" /> 
                </File> 
            </Route>
        </Routes> 
        <IdlePurgePolicy timeToLive="5" timeUnit="seconds"/>
    </Routing>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.avispl" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" /> 
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="conference.logger" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConferenceLog" />
        </Logger> 
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

CommandsController.java

```
private static final String LOG_FILE_NAME = "logFileName";
    private static final String CONFERENCE_LOGGER = "conference.logger";
    private static final Logger conferenceLogger = Logger.getLogger(CONFERENCE_LOGGER);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "log_test")
    public @ResponseBody void logTest(@RequestParam(required = true) long duration) {
        conferenceLogger.debug("test");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was breakpointing in the source for log4j; the IdlePurgePolicy class, specifically the method below (purge())

I noticed that my breakpoint would only be hit when the first log was being closed and never after that (explains behavior described in question above).  I didnt go too deep but I believe its removing the appender and it never gets re-added

However the real fix was updating my log4j2 version from 2.5 to 2.11.1

```
public void purge() {
        long createTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeToLive;
        for (Entry<String, Long> entry : appendersUsage.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() < createTime) {
                LOGGER.debug("Removing appender " + entry.getKey());
                appendersUsage.remove(entry.getKey());
                routingAppender.deleteAppender(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
```